# .NET membership, role and authorize in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, authorization

Ok, so I setup my MVC3 to use the default registration, login and membership from .NET. Just ran the services wizard onto the database.

Now, I put in the `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` portion to each Action that I want restricted in the controllers.

The problem I have is that despite being logged in, I still get prompted to log-in whenever I try to access these "restricted actions", I get prompted with the log-in screen.

What is the default role or members in .NET membership? Or can I change the Authorize filter/rule to suit all logged in members?

Thanks! Any piece of help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Default is no role. You have to add each "Admin" to the Admin Role

Comment: So you mean just [Authorize] will do?

Comment: Yes. Until you actually add roles and assign different users to different roles, just use [Authorize]. Later you may decide that certain Controllers should be available to different Roles. Then use Roles distinction.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, please write an answer so I can mark it as one. Highly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything more than `[Authorize]` to force users to Authenticate.

Later, once you have many controllers and want to distinguish between which user groups are allowed to see which Controllers or Actions, you can add add roles and close off Controllers to distinct roles:

examples

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminReports()
```